# com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner cannot access class sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins

after installing openjdk17 on my jenkins, I get the following stacktrace while signing the apk-package using https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-signing/:

```
10:59:59 FATAL: class com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner (in unnamed module @0x38dba2ff) cannot access class sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.x509 to unnamed module @0x38dba2ff
10:59:59 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner (in unnamed module @0x38dba2ff) cannot access class sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.x509 to unnamed module @0x38dba2ff
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.getSupportedAlgorithmId(V1SchemeSigner.java:625)
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.<clinit>(V1SchemeSigner.java:541)
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.<init>(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:149)
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.<init>(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:52)
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine$Builder.build(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:902)
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.sign(ApkSigner.java:260)
10:59:59    at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.sign(ApkSigner.java:179)
10:59:59    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.androidsigning.SignApksBuilder$SignApkCallable.invoke(SignApksBuilder.java:510)
10:59:59    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.androidsigning.SignApksBuilder$SignApkCallable.invoke(SignApksBuilder.java:464)
10:59:59    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1198)
10:59:59    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1181)
10:59:59    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.androidsigning.SignApksBuilder.perform(SignApksBuilder.java:359)
10:59:59    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
10:59:59    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
10:59:59    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
10:59:59    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

As this worked with openjdk11 I configured my pipeline for using openjkd11 again. To verify this, I added a build step that executes "java --version" before starting the Android Signing Plugin and it says

```
10:59:59 + java --version
10:59:59 openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17
10:59:59 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
10:59:59 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Changed environment using "update-alternatives --config java" to openjdk 11 does not help anymore (?).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem is the AppSigner Plugin itself. It's meant to run with Java8 but it also runs with Java11. Knowing this means you can change the default java version using "update-alternatives --config java" and restart Jenkins. Now you see the correct java version in the interface at Manage Jenkins --> System Information. It's not sufficient to just change the default java version assuming that this is used at pipeline execution stage because the error comes from the plugin running in the context of jenkins.